# Why are printers, earplugs, and shoes on topic, but not video, graphic editing, or computer vision?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, on-topic

We have this question about earplugs [What kind of earplugs are best for concert photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41801/what-kind-of-earplugs-are-best-for-concert-photography), which has remained open by consensus despite some interest in closing it as off-topic. There's also this lovely one about shoes: [What kind of shoes are best for wedding photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41921/what-kind-of-shoes-are-best-for-wedding-photography).

We also get a bunch of printer questions, like, recently:

- [Why do professional printers still feature cartridges?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/95012/why-do-professional-printers-still-feature-cartridges)
- [Best way to avoid print head clogging when not using printer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94979/best-way-to-avoid-print-head-clogging-when-not-using-printer)

and these also generally get some back-and-forth on topicality.

Meanwhile, we've generally decided that [questions about industrial optics without applicability to general photography are off-topic](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/are-questions-about-industrial-optics-on-topic), as are [questions about using cameras to measure things](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5358/is-photography-for-technical-documentation-and-or-measurement-off-topic), and [questions about video](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/yet-another-angle-on-video-questions).

What's the difference here? Why does one category — stuff which is only peripheral to this light and optics and recording medium thing — get a pass, while the other does not?

Answer (score 9):

Here's my take. We want this site to continue to grow are around a *[community of practice](http://wenger-trayner.com/introduction-to-communities-of-practice/)*. In this case, that community is [defined right first thing in the tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Photography Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional, enthusiast and amateur photographers.

A community of practice is a

> group of people who share a concern or a passion for something they do and learn how to do it better as they interact regularly.

And that's basically the guideline I'd suggest.

- Is it relevant to the community of people interested in the art, science, craft, and business of *making images with light*? On topic.
- Is it instead using the same tools but really only connected through gear and not through the community of practice? Off-topic.

Through this lens (heh), some very similar questions may be on different sides of the line. That's okay.

Of course, there's often some overlap with related communities — astronomy, machine learning, etc. But for questions about those, the *making photographs* aspect should be centered, or else we should nicely redirect to a different Stack Exchange network site *where the community of practice is aligned*.

House painters and landscape painters both use brushes and paint, but those aren't the same communities of practice. Same here. It's possible that a house painter also does artistic painting as a hobby, but that doesn't mean the circles collapse: many people are members of multiple communities.

I've heard the argument that it'd be better to be more expansive, that we'd get more people that way. I think this is actually counterproductive, and it's better to focus on the concern for photography itself.

Comment: If we have a problem growing the community here, I think the main issue isn't that we're too exclusive with this kind of question. I think it's that we don't have a good answer for two _other_ things. First, we don't handle "first camera?" or "next lens?" questions well, and while there are good reasons for that (those questions are terrible!) that's the pipeline/gateway to the hobby/craft. Second, since we don't allow "What do you think of my photo?" questions, we have never successfully attracted many questions _actually about photographs_.

Comment: +1 for bringing the focus (!) to an easily-remembered and used phrase, **community of practice**. It's not the end of the conversation that settles all, but it's a good metric, or a good "smell test".