# Can I ask a question like this?

Tags: support, video, post-review

Having read this [meta answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/93/13495), Am I good to go with a question like the following

> When I'm using my compact digital camera, what is the best way to hold the lens cap. *(this is very useful when recording videos with the camera as the lens cap impact with the camera records a 'tik-tock' sound in the recorded audio of the video)*

Is this kind of question considered off topic? I think `avp.SE` is not the place for this question.

Comment: There is a tiny amount of merit for stills as well (to avoid contamination/dust/being blown into view at the inopportune moment/etc)

Comment: @RowlandShaw errr could you please explain what you're saying a little bit more?

Comment: Whilst you want to keep the lens cap from making noise when videoing, you may want advice that will stop "bad things" getting in...

Comment: @RowlandShaw Gotit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the logic [from the top-voted answer to the previous meta discussion](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/291/1943), I think this question is fine for topicality. That's because while the example annoyance is video related, there are plenty of factors which apply to still photography as well. Just be prepared for answers to focus more on those concerns than on the video aspect.

Also, it's a little bit on the edge for being a discussion rather than answerable, but the answers so far seem useful.