# FAQ inconsistency with video?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I asked a question about video processing in imovie (i.e., post-processing). It's about to be, or is, closed as off-topic. OK, fine, my bad.

To avoid future errors, I belated read the 'what can I ask' help. It pointed me to [Can I ask Videography related questions?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/can-i-ask-videography-related-questions?answertab=votes#tab-top); the most active response which was the first thing I was shown) and the top-voted response are neutral-to-positive. Now, I appreciate that there are distinctions being drawn here, but I submit that when the help center points to a faq question as an explanation, somehow the result of reading that question and it's accepted answer should not require quite so much reading and thinking to get the point, which is, 'video is prima-facia off topic but occasionally yields an acceptable question in the intersection.'

Answer (score 1):

The answer you linked to here is quite old and things have firmed up with the Videography sister-site (amongst others), but it's still pretty accurate. The general practice here has been to assess the video question for relevancy to photography and adjust to reflect. Otherwise, if not relevant, move it to the proper site. That's pretty consistent with that answer there and has been.

Also, I think the [help covers it](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), videography is off topic. It just so happens that some videography questions can be recovered and we try to do that.

Comment: Fix the help center not to link to it.

Comment: The answer in that question is absolutely consistent with our activities, so I see no need to do that.

Comment: See edit to question.

Answer (score 1):

On Stack Exchange, "most active" just means "most recently created or edited". It isn't a metric of relevance. The top-voted answer is clear:

When a question could be applicable in both situations, they're welcome. This is often the case with lighting and composition, but less so with post-processing nor  with questions about FPS.

and that answer is considerably more-voted than the next-up answer.

I think the text given in the off-topic close reason is perfect and succinct. It says:

> **This question is about video in a context that is not likely to be [relevant to still photography](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/291/).**

And note that the link goes directly to the answer which specifically explains that (so the sorting order isn't as important).

I agree with Joanne that this isn't really a big problem, but, sure, changing the FAQ to match the close text wouldn't hurt.