# Reopen my question about the Fuji X-T Series

Tags: discussion

[What about the Fuji X-T series makes it bad for video?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69105/what-about-the-fuji-x-t-series-makes-it-bad-for-video)

Closed for being about Video..

The tag [video](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) states "Questions about video mode in camera equipment."

The [Help](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states "using photographic equipment"

The [Help](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) goes on to link to [Can I ask Videography related questions?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/can-i-ask-videography-related-questions) for what Video is on-topic.

That question has positive upvotes on all of the following statements:

> I Also agree with Edd's answer, in that some level of video related questions is acceptable. Particularly those about shooting video with cameras aimed primarily at stills shots.

-Simon P Stevens

> Check out Brian Storm's project "1976" here. In the digital age, all is fair game! It is limited thinking to hold out against videography...in regards to photography anyway.

-Rob Clement

> Wikipedia seems to think that it doesn't matter if the image is moving or still, it's photography.

-ioSamurai

> I think this is sentiment that Edd alluded to. So the capturing the image part is common ground, and fair game, but asking how to edit video together, or overdub with an audio track isn't.

-Rowland Shaw (moderator)

> I think the focus should remain as a stills photography Q&A site, but inevitably there will be people who want to purchase a camera for both, or who consider themselves primarily a stills photographer but who wants to record some video whilst on holiday, for example.
>
> I think what I'm suggesting is that we discourage too many serious, detailed questions specifically about video, but that if a question mentions video we don't automatically close it, and have a [videography] tag for such occasions. Example questions I'm thinking of are things like

-Edd

> Since many DSLRs are now able to record video, I do think the two are related.

-chris

> I totally agree with this. While I'm generally in favour of keeping this site dedicated to photography rather than video, there certainly is an overlap, and some level of video related questions is definitely acceptable, particularly those about shooting video with DSLRs, compacts and cameras who's primary function is still shooting.

-Simon P Stevens

---

I'd also point out that it is frowned upon by SE to migrate overlapping content to a beta stackexchange.

[Should beta-sites be listed for migration suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178444/should-beta-sites-be-listed-for-migration-suggestions)

> we don't establish migration paths to a site that is still in its beta period. We don't want to send content from one site to another unless we're certain that the target site is a permanent fixture. There are exceptions to this; moderators can migrate relatively new questions to sites not in the current migration path, but this ability should be used sparingly. A question should be of much better than average quality, and all hope of it being on topic for the current site should be exhausted

-Tim Post, Community Manager

---

And yet I'm being told my Question is not on-topic. That's not really acceptable for someone to read through every bit of your [Help](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Meta](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/). Confirm that everything they are asking is in fact on-topic and then be told that all of that is out of date. Please reopen my question as it is very clearly on-topic.

---

Edit:

2 things - first to whomever downvoted, that's just dumb. This is important and needs to be addressed. If you don't agree with reopening that's fine (though I think you're wrong) but downvoting this as a discussion just says its not a discussion worth having.

Now to address this so-called idea that it's been resolved per Philip in Comments. Here are just a quick few questions to counter that all of which are open, with answers, and high rep members discussing things on them:

- [Apply adjustment brush area to video in Lightroom 5.3](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56948/apply-adjustment-brush-area-to-video-in-lightroom-5-3)
- [What's a good software to combine all the frames in a video into a photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46906/whats-a-good-software-to-combine-all-the-frames-in-a-video-into-a-photo)
- [How much more would a DSLR cost with no time limit on video recording?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34892/how-much-more-would-a-dslr-cost-with-no-time-limit-on-video-recording)
- [How can I extract still frames from an MPEG video with Photoshop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67766/how-can-i-extract-still-frames-from-an-mpeg-video-with-photoshop)
- [Can my Nikon D70 take video?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65376/can-my-nikon-d70-take-video) (special note, the person telling me my question is off-topic and this has been resolved since Video launched in 2011 is the same person who answered this one two months ago)

Comment: 1) Please stop making personal comments; if nothing else, they're really not helping your case. 2) Voting on meta is different from the main site - it's an "agree" / "disagree" thing, not "this is a good / bad question".

Comment: I didn't make personal comments. I referenced what comment I was editing it for. I'm not attacking you or anyone else. I'm very clearly indicating that my topic to any new user would appear on topic.  @PhilipKendall

Answer (score 3):

Actually, sorry, I don't think it's clearly on topic. The help link on the main site clearly states that is *not* about videography that is unrelated to photography, despite linking to a 5 year old, very early, meta question and the help also distinctly links to the videography site for questions on that purpose.

I think what may come of this meta post is a revisit of the help contents. The community is entitled to reestablish the view of what is off topic over time and given that we have a site now for the purpose of videography it makes sense to ask there. I can, if you want, migrate it for you, it is much more commonly accepted for us to migrate to Video (and one of their mods is very active here) than you would normally see for a mature/beta arrangement.

Comment: Everything including the most upvoted Answer is neutral to positive about what I asked. The only things that Answer and really Question make clear are off-topic are Video Editing/Post Production, and Audio Capture. Neither of which I asked about. That goes for the top-voted Answer as well as every single thing I quoted.

Comment: As far as Community Reestablishing its views. Sure you can. But you haven't. There's no new meta, new metas have all been closed and referred back to that one. So saying this is an old meta is not at all a valid point.

Comment: @Ryan The community *has* reestablished its views. We have very consistently closed and/or migrated video-only questions to Video Production since that site has been in public beta. You're potentially right that we need to update the documentation to more clearly reflect that change, but it *has* happened.

Comment: @PhilipKendall please see my edit which includes numerous instances including one you yourself recently answered.